# Вычисление положения 3D-координаты методом нелинейной оптимизации

Tags: c++, opencv

Есть точка в 3D с неизвестными координатами. Она видна на изображениях, взятых со стерео камеры. Координаты на изображениях известны с погрешностью, так же известны параметры стереокамеры. Необходимо найти координаты точки в 3D, минимизируя суммарную среднеквадратичную ошибку репроекции, где эталонными координатами будут измеренные напрямую (то есть координаты проекций этой точки на левом и правом изображениях).

Для этого я думаю подойдёт библиотека [ceres-solver](http://ceres-solver.org/). Однако не смог найти примера, как это реализовать. Да и в принципе, мало знаком с задачами нелинейной оптимизации.

При этом, я могу вычислить с приближенные значение положения точки в пространстве через длину базовой лини и значения диспарантности. Далее, как мне кажется, необходимо "уточнить" эти 3D координаты через среднеквадратичную ошибку репроекции. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Если точка одна, солвер не нужен. Из проекции точки на одной камере восстанавливается прямая в 3D. Две такие прямые скрещиваются в пространстве, можно найти точку наименее удалённую от обоих. Все алгоритмы "точные", минимизировать нелинейные функции не придётся. Много готовых решений в [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html).

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, в общем случае необходимо определять положение от одной до 6 одновременно находящихся в кадре точек объекта. Не могли бы вы, порекомендовать что-то из OpenCV?

Comment: Я там оставил ссылку на раздел API "3d reconstruction". Конкретно эта функция https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gad3fc9a0c82b08df034234979960b778c